# jQuery AJAX form goes to PHP file doesn't Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having some problems with jQuery AJAX. I have a form that is validated with this Js controller, and I want it to validate with PHP via AJAX, and perform an action based on the response. Here is my Js code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form.loginSubmit').on('submit',function(event){
    var that = $(this),
        url=that.attr('action'),
        type=that.attr('method'),
        data={};

    //data.text_login_username=that.val()
    that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value){ 
        var that=$(this), 
            name=that.attr('name'); 
            value=that.val(); 
            data[name]=value;
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        contenType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.allClear==1){
                window.location = "http://localhost/ServerObserver/dashboard.html";
            }
            else if(response.allClear==0){
                console.log("[loc.W]: Wrong username or password.");
            }
            else{
                console.log("[loc.E]: Something went terribly wrong.");
            }
        }

    });

return 0;

});


});
```

The problem is that my browser redirects to the PHP file, and not the `window.location` specified in the script. Here is the PHP file for reference:

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['text_login_username'],$_POST['text_login_password']))
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $loginResult=array();
    $dbcon=getConnection();
    $userName=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['text_login_username']);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['text_login_password']);
    $loginQuery="SELECT * FROM userData WHERE userName='$userName' AND userPassword='$password'";
    $queryResult=mysqli_query($dbcon, $loginQuery);
    $legalRows=$queryResult->num_rows;

    if($legalRows==1)
    {
        setcookie("currentUser", $userName);
        $loginResult['allClear']=1; 
    }
    else
    {
        $loginResult['allClear']=0;
    }

    echo json_encode($loginResult);

}



?>
```

I simply see this `checkLogin.php` when I submit the form. I'm completely confused, as this was working perfectly a couple days ago! [Here](http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js) is the version of jQuery I'm using.

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: Could you show us the forms markup?

Comment: Try the option dataType: "json" for $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might just need to do an `event.preventDefault();` at the start to stop it from going to the php file when you submit the form.

Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/